# Javascript: mute/unmute button doesn't work TypeError: null is not an object

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-video

My site displays a video in autoplay (no controls) and I would like to have a button in a fixed position to mute/unmute the audio while scrolling the page.
I did it (as visible here by code snippet) but while here works on my site it doesn't (if I push the button nothing happens) and console displays this: " TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'video.muted') "

Why? Any suggestion to fix this problem?
I am a newbie in javascript.
Thank you in advance!

```js
var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

function myFunction() {
    video.muted = !video.muted;
    btn.innerHTML = video.muted ? "Unmute":'Mute';
}
```

```css
.video-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px auto 80px;
}

.video-description {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 66%;
  margin: 0 auto 24px;
  font: inherit;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}


#myVideo {
  border-radius: 5px;
  max-width: 46%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#myBtn {
  top: 10%;
  right: 3%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 50;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #D3D3D3;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<section class="video-container">

  <div class="video-description">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>

  <video id="myVideo" autoplay loop>
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>

  <div class="content">

    <button id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">Toggle Mute</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce. It works perfectly for me.

Comment: it looks like your getElementById return a null, it might be because your javascript code is running before the html is fully loaded, how do you connect your javascript code to the html?

Comment: Make sure you are referencing the elements in javascript BELOW the actual elements themselves. Otherwise the javascript doesn't know the elements exist as it will be set before the DOM loads them.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, you were right, I had the link to my JS file ( <script type="text/javascript" src="js/home.js"></script> ) before the <body> instead after. Now it perfectly work in my site as well!